# Bootstrap grid How do I make my columns collapse together?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to html, css, & bootstrap. I am trying to make both my white and gray boxes collapse together but I can't seem to get it.
I am looking for something like this when collapsing.

```
123
456

1
4
2
5
3
6
```

Here is the code: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/FreddieCabrera/full/yegJgY/)

Also if you guys have some more pointers please lmk what i'm doing wrong here. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could go about this is to separate the `thumbnail` from your cart controls so you have more control over each section.

Create a div(s) after closing the `thumbnail` div so you can style those elements apart from the thumbnails.

See working Snippet at Full Page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #2b2a2f;
}
h1 {
  color: #D1D2D6;
}
div.thumbnail {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.cart-container {
  background: #D1D2D6;
  border-top: 3px solid #2b2a2f;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px;
}
.cart-controls {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.cart-controls h2 {
  color: #FDFEFE;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cart-controls h5 {
  color: #FDFEFE;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.cart-controls select.select-width {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.cart-container .btn-cart {
  background-color: #EF2E27;
  color: #FDFEFE;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Yeezy 350</h1>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://bit.ly/1JPSaOa">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-container">
        <div class="cart-controls">
          <h2>$200</h2>

          <h5>QTY</h5>
          <select class="form-control select-width">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-cart btn-block">Add to Cart</button>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Yeezy 351</h1>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://bit.ly/1JPSaOa">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-container">
        <div class="cart-controls">
          <h2>$200</h2>

          <select class="form-control select-width">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
          <h5>QTY</h5>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-cart btn-block">Add to Cart</button>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Yeezy 352</h1>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://bit.ly/1JPSaOa">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-container">
        <div class="cart-controls">
          <h2>$200</h2>

          <select class="form-control select-width">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
          <h5>QTY</h5>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-cart btn-block">Add to Cart</button>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Yeezy 353</h1>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://bit.ly/1JPSaOa">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-container">
        <div class="cart-controls">
          <h2>$200</h2>

          <h5>QTY</h5>
          <select class="form-control select-width">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-cart btn-block">Add to Cart</button>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Yeezy 354</h1>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://bit.ly/1JPSaOa">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-container">
        <div class="cart-controls">
          <h2>$200</h2>

          <select class="form-control select-width">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
          <h5>QTY</h5>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-cart btn-block">Add to Cart</button>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1>Yeezy 355</h1>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://bit.ly/1JPSaOa">
      </div>
      <div class="cart-container">
        <div class="cart-controls">
          <h2>$200</h2>

          <select class="form-control select-width">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
          <h5>QTY</h5>

        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-cart btn-block">Add to Cart</button>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Man thats dope! Thats exactly what I needed thanks. I need to compare your code with mine so that I can make sure I understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `<div class="col-md-4">`

To:

`<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">`

Comment: That solves the stacking issue but both boxes separate and all the content inside the gray box messes up.